# wpf c# static combobox selection needs to update second combobox that makes a DB call

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF, using DevExpress MVVM, I have a static combobox that when the user selects a day, I want to update the second combobox by passing an int day and making a DB call to refresh that combo box with routes based off that day.  Here's what I have:

-->

```
    <Label Content="Route:" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,60,0,0" Name="lblRoute" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="127,65,0,0" Name="cboRoute" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
                DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RouteList}"  DisplayMemberPath="{Binding RouteName}" SelectedValue="{Binding RouteID}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
 public ObservableCollection<RouteTest> BindRouteComboBox2(int day)
     {
          mgr = new SRMSRailManagerBLL();
        mgr.OpenConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRMSSqlProvider"].ConnectionString);
        //might not want to pass dataset
        _routeDS = mgr.getRoutesForCombo(day);
        _routeDV = _routeDS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        //cboRoute.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        //cboRoute.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["RouteName"].ToString();
        //cboRoute.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["RouteID"].ToString();
        _routeList = new ObservableCollection<RouteTest>();
        foreach (DataRow row in _routeDV.Table.Rows)
        {
            RouteTest r = new RouteTest(Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[0]), row.ItemArray[1].ToString());
            _routeList.Add(r);

        }


        mgr.CloseConnection();
         return _routeList;
```

When I click my first combobox, I get the 'Monday' populated in my _SelectionChanged(), what I want is the Tag value of '1', so that I can pass to my BindRouteComboBox(day) procedure to update the second combo box to only show routes for day 1, instead of every route in my DB table.  This should be simple and I've gotta be missing something simple here.

Thanks,

Comment: Remove the code behind and use a proper ViewModel, also, don't use `System.Data` classes with WPF. Create a proper data model instead.

Comment: It seems odd to me to bind your second combobox to something from code behind rather than in a view model. Proper MVVM format would suggest you create a model for your dataset that is getting returned then create an OvservableCollection<Model> in your view model. Then since your day variable is bound, in the set event you could call a method to fill your collection with items.

Comment: like I said, I'm new to this, so learning the process, I have my Data and Business Logic in their own .DLL's.  Wasn't happy about passing up a DataSet, but I just need it to work.  Would rather pass up a class and deal with it, but need to pass up a DS so I can figure out how everything works.

Comment: Pulled everything out of the View code behind to the ViewMode, created a Route class implementing INotifyCollectionChanged created using my BLL and DAL .DLL"S, binded properly, everything shows up, but when I click the first combo box it doesn't update the second, even though the binding calls a proc to update the INotifyCollectionChanged class with new values.

Comment: This can't be that hard, I want to pick Day 1-7 on the first combo, and it calls the .BLL which calls the DAL which passes up a Observable List of <Routes> and update the second combo box with the new set of routes based off day.  This is really frustrating.

Comment: should this not do it?

Comment: oh Hell yeah, got it working, creating a new object each time was the problem,  thanks everyone, I spend plenty of time watch videos and reading other post.  Now time to clean up :), thx

Answer (score 0):

Hi use SelectedValue instead of SelectedValuePath

```
string temp = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: yeah, I tried that but it doesn't like it.  Mostly likely b/c it's mapped to my ViewModel